# In Python, what does getresponse() return?

Tags: python, linux, http, unix

```
 import httplib
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(head)
    conn.request("HEAD",tail)
    res = conn.getresponse()
```

I can get the **res.status** , which is the http status code.

What other elements can I get?
Why is it that when I do print **res**, it won't print the dictionary?  I just want to see the keys that are in that dictionary...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can always inspect an object using [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir); that will show you which attributes it has.

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.nl")
>>> conn.request("HEAD", "/index.html")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> dir(res)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', '_check_close', '_method', '_read_chunked', '_read_status', '_safe_read', 'begin', 'chunk_left', 'chunked', 'close', 'debuglevel', 'fp', 'getheader', 'getheaders', 'isclosed', 'length', 'msg', 'read', 'reason', 'status', 'strict', 'version', 'will_close']
```

Likewise, you can invoke [`help`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help), which will show an object's documentation, if it has a `__doc__` attribute. As you can see, this is the case for `res`, so try:

```
>>> help(res)
```

Other than that, the documentation states that [`getresponse`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.getresponse) returns an [`HTTPResponse`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httpresponse-objects) object. Thus, as you can read there (and in `help(res)`), the following properties and methods are defined on `HTTPResponse` objects:

- `HTTPResponse.read([amt])`:
  Reads and returns the response body, or up to the next amt bytes.
- `HTTPResponse.getheader(name[, default])`:
  Get the contents of the header name, or default if there is no matching header.
- `HTTPResponse.getheaders()`:
  Return a list of (header, value) tuples.
  *(New in version 2.4.)*
- `HTTPResponse.msg`:
  A mimetools.Message instance containing the response headers.
- `HTTPResponse.version`:
  HTTP protocol version used by server. 10 for HTTP/1.0, 11 for HTTP/1.1.
- `HTTPResponse.status`:
  Status code returned by server.
- `HTTPResponse.reason`:
  Reason phrase returned by server.